# mysql: i want to authenticate as user on remote host but..give me localhost

Tags: mariadb

I want to login to mysql db with another user
I create the user

```
mysql -u root

create USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' REQUIRE SSL; flush privileges;
```

grant privileges

```
 grant all on *.* to 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; flush privileges;
```

but mysql refuse connect and "force" localhost !

```
mysql -h myhost -p

Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

the tcp port 3306 is open

```
telnet-ssl myshost 3306

    Escape character is '^]'.
    Y
    ******-MariaDB...

ss -tulnepona|grep 3306

tcp   LISTEN    0      80                                   *:3306             *:*     users:(("mariadbd",pid=13501,fd=20)) uid:27 ino:39020 sk:45 cgroup:unreachable:1 v6only:0 <->                           
tcp   TIME-WAIT 0      0                                [::1]:59876        [::1]:3306  timer:(timewait,53sec,0) ino:0 sk:47
```

why force the localhost and don't connect to remote server?
Server is mariadb on slackware-15, i don't use $HOME/.my.cnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, I have to test it from a remote site, not from localsite